# How do I specify which API data I want to use?

Tags: javascript, rest, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa Skill (using v2 and javascript) and I'm attempting to make an API `GET` call to the USDA API.

At this point I've copy/pasted from [here](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/4a46da08-d1b8-4d8e-9277-055307a9bf4a/alexa-skill-recipe-update-call-and-get-data-from-external-apis) and I'm using the USDA API example from [here](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html) (with some minor changes). as an attempt just to get the connection to work and return anything that proves it worked.

**The error I currently receive is:** `Error handled: TypeError: Cannot read property 'generalSearchInput' of undefined at Object.handle (/var/task/index.js:39:32)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`

**Directly before the error I get the return of:** every entry about Cottage Cheese that is in the USDA API, I.E. *WAY too much* from the `console.log(response)`. I just want the first one, or even just the name.

**Console logs have told me that I am receiving data back from the call, so I know it is working. My question is: How do I set the `speechOutput` to the specific piece of information I need, rather than the entire API object that is returned?**

**The `speechOutput` that I'm looking for should say:** *Cottage Cheese*

**The response that I am receiving is:** *Output from Alexa saying:*

> Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again

**index.js**

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Welcome to food points! What food would you like to know about?';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const FoodPointsIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'FoodPointsIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        console.log("THIS.EVENT = " + JSON.stringify(this.event));
        var speakOutput = 'Sorry, there was an error';
        //var https = require('https');
        const { requestEnvelope } = handlerInput;
        const userInput = Alexa.getSlotValue(requestEnvelope, 'FoodQuery');

        const response = await httpGet();

        console.log(response);

            /*
            const food = userInput;
            speakOutput = food;
        */
        speakOutput = response.value.generalSearchInput;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();

    }
};
const TestIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'TestIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        console.log("THIS.EVENT = " + JSON.stringify(this.event));
        var speakOutput = 'Sorry, there was an error';
        const { requestEnvelope } = handlerInput;
        const userInput = Alexa.getSlotValue(requestEnvelope, 'TestQuery');

            const food = userInput;
            speakOutput = food;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};

function httpGet() {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
        host: 'api.nal.usda.gov',
        port: 443,
        path: '/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=DEMO_KEY&query=Cheddar%20Cheese',
        method: 'GET',
    };
    var https = require('https');

    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let returnData = '';

      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        returnData += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
      });

      response.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
    request.end();
  }));
}

/****************************REMEMBER TO UPDATE THIS*************************/
const HelpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'You can say hello to me! How can I help?';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && (Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
                || Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Goodbye!';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        // Any cleanup logic goes here.
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
    }
};

// The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
// It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers
// for your intents by defining them above, then also adding them to the request
// handler chain below.
const IntentReflectorHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const intentName = Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope);
        const speakOutput = `You just triggered ${intentName}`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
// stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
// the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below.
const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log(`~~~~ Error handled: ${error.stack}`);
        const speakOutput = `Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again.`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

// The SkillBuilder acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
// payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
// defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        FoodPointsIntentHandler,
        TestIntentHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        IntentReflectorHandler, // make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers
    )
    .addErrorHandlers(
        ErrorHandler,
    )
    .lambda();
```

Comment: For skill-related logs, you have to use aws cloudwatch. So First, Check Wheather the intent is triggered and the Next check weather response you are giving is in the right format. All of your ```console.log()``` will appear in cloudwatch.

Comment: @sharankenam Thank you! I got cloudwatch up and running, and I added the error to the description.

Comment: Can you add the response you are getting from api. I think the value you are trying to access is  ```response.value.generalSearchInput``` and their is no key name ```generalSearchInput``` in the response so that is the reason it is giving undefined.

Comment: @sharankenam the response is huge, it's essentially every item of every "cottage cheese" product they have available. I'm just not sure how to narrow down to specific things. If you we're to use the API example I have linked, the response appears to be everything on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Hopefully this can help somebody who may be stuck.

I was calling the API data incorrectly.

**The code that did what I needed**

```
var nvArray = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < response.foods[0].foodNutrients.length; i++) {
            var nvArrayString = [response.foods[0].foodNutrients[i].nutrientName] + '';
            var nvShortString = nvArrayString.split(',', 1);
            nvArray.push(nvShortString);
        }

        var nvArraySpeakOutputString = nvArray.join();
```

**The actual piece of code that fixed my errors**

`response.foods[0].foodNutrients[i].nutrientName`

I was looking at the wrong part of the data being given to me, and thus calling something that didn't exist, i.e. `response.value.generalSearchInput`.

*Additional information that may be helpful*

`nvArray` is used so that I can put multiple variables from the data into one place (using `push` and `pop`).

This allowed me to `split` the data into shorter pieces each time the loop runs (used to keep the output from being a wall of text for each item).

`nvArraySpeakOutputString` is the `nvArray` `join`ed together, allowing Alexa to speak it all as one variable, preventing me from having to type

> `varA + '. next ' + varB`

and so on for each item.

Anyway, hope this helps somebody at some point!